# Design Pattern: managing a limited number of a resource

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, architecture

I am in the process of designing a feature for a system where I strongly feel that there must be a pattern for this out there, that I should know about before diving into the code.

The scenario is this:

- I have a pool of resources of which I have a limited number.
- I have a variable number of consumers that use those resources; each consumer needs exactly one resource, and it may not use the same resource as any other consumer at a given time.
- The consumers are divided into a fixed number of groups, and the system needs to guarantee that there is a minimum of one resource for each group.
- The number of consumers in each group varies over time; they are allocated and deallocated as needed.

My current approach is to put the resources into two stacks at startup: one "emergency stack" and one "common stack". The emergency stack will contain the same number of resources as there are groups (so, one for each group). The rest of the available resources go into the common stack.

When a new consumer is about to be created, the system will request a resource. If there are resources available in the common stack, one will be popped from it and returned to the caller. If the common stack is empty, a resource may be popped from the emergency stack instead, *but only if there are no consumers within the same group that already has an emergency resource*.

Whenever a consumer within a group can be deallocated, the associated resource will be returned, and pushed onto one of the resource stacks. The code responsible for deallocating consumers will make sure to always return any emergency resources first, so that the emergency stack is filled, before returned resources are being pushed onto the common stack.

I feel that this is the sort of problem for which there ought to exist a design pattern that has been tested and proven to work well, so I call out to the community: do you know of such a pattern? If so, I kindly ask you to enlighten me.

**Update**

The solution is now implemented, using bits and pieces from various answers to this question. I published [a blog post](http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2009/10/08/A-partitioned-pool-in-C.aspx) about it.

Comment: I feel that this will be one of the cases where I wished I could spread the "accepted answer" reward across more than one answer. We start to get a clear picture on how to do it by assembling bits and pieces...

Comment: The functionality is now implemented, and the answer from @Steve was the one that pointed us into direction. I will do a write-up of the solution (probably as a blog post), and update the question text with a summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably have a single resource stack, an array/map keyed by group of counts, and a count of groups that have no resources.

To allocate...

```
if group-counts [group] == 0
  pop resource from stack
  increment group-counts [group]
  decrement reserved-count

elseif reserved-count < stack.size
  pop resource from stack
  increment group-counts [group]

else
  fail
```

The key point is that the stack is never allowed to get smaller than the number of groups that still have the right to demand an immediate resource.

One advantage to this approach is that you can make it a little more flexible if needed. Suppose one group has a special requirement, so it may need two resources at any point.

```
if group-counts [group] < group-reserved [group]
  pop resource from stack
  increment group-counts [group]
  decrement reserved-count

elseif reserved-count < stack.size
  pop resource from stack
  increment group-counts [group]

else
  fail
```

The reserved-count in this case starts as the sum of all group-reserved[] values.

The release logic for this case is...

```
push resource to stack
decrement group-counts [group]
if group-counts [group] < group-reserved [group]
  increment reserved-count
```

For the simple case, use "if group-counts [group] == 0".

Comment: Steve, thanks for your quick answer! It's a good one too, but after examining, I find one case where it is less than optimal; say we have `reserved-count = 7`, and one group takes 3, and two others take one each. Now the first group would be denied a 4th resource. If the first group returns one of its resources, and then requests a new one, it will still be denied even though there are enough resources to serve the request; we have only 4 consumers without resources, and 6 available resources so the first group would in theory be able to get two at that time. You still get an upvote though :o)

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, there isn't a mistake. All that's missing is the free logic, which decrements the group-count and *may* need to increment the reserved-count (if the group-count drops low enough, normally to zero). With group-count decremented, the "if" always succeeds - the freed resource can be re-acquired.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any pattern, but I think you can **simplify** your approach:

If your resource pool does know which group has a resource, you don't need an extra emergency stack.

1. Provide all resources from the same stack.
2. If the number of *available resources* is less than the number of *guaranteed resources* 
   **plus** the number of *used guaranteed resources*, don't return a resource if the requesting group already has a resource.

Other than that I think your approach is sound and concise, I don't believe there's a better way. (But I might be wrong, of course)

Comment: DR, thanks for your answer. However, as far as I can tell it does suffer from the same issue as the answer provided by @Steve (it can produce scenarios where a group will be denied resources even though there are enough available resources to serve the request).

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't find a counter-example. Can you give one? (I don't really understand the one you provided for Steve)

Comment: OK, don't, bother I found one. I think I can updated my answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could also swap the logic around (it might result in cleaner code):

Assign each group a resource from the start. Keep the rest of the resources in a list of "free" resources.
Any consumer that asks for a resource does so through a group resource allocator that either just gives out the default group resource or queries for a free resource.
On returning the resources, first fill group resource hole, then start filling free resource list.

So you end up with a pool of free resources.
One resource allocator per group with access to the free resource pool and a default resource.
Consumers interact with the group allocator.

Comment: Thanks Daren. This sounds a lot like the approach we have at the drawing table right now.

Comment: Yes it is. Just flipped on where to retrieve the resource first: Instead of "emergency" use a "default" resource. The effect is the same, but the logic might end up simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem like a very odd version of a pool.

For example, if you have seven groups and seven resources in the default pool, seven in 'emergency' pool. If each group requests one resource the default pool is exhausted, and then if any one group requests two more resources starvation occurs, with only eight of the fourteen resources in use. Even if you change it to use the group-specific resource first, you still find situations of starvation with only 8/14 utilisation.

Why exactly does it matter that the second request for a resource should be the one to fail instead of the first ( another way of looking at the "there is a minimum of one resource for each group" requirement )?

Comment: It is odd, indeed. The only hard requirements are those listed in the bullet points in my question. The rest are my thoughts around implementation. It has shifted some after reading some of the answers. Feel free to share any alternate approach, however different it may be. It would me most valuable input to the feature design.

Comment: If there is a good reason for the guarantee of at least one resource per pool, then I'd prioritise taking the guaranteed resource over the pooled resource ( which removes some cases of premature starvation ). Otherwise I'd just use a standard pool, as that will give better utilisation of the resources in more situations.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. At a high level the issue is you have 2 types of resource requests:a high priority request which is not allowed to fail, and a standard request which can fail.

One possible way to handle this is if your consumers can be suspended. If that is possible you can implement a two way communication between the consumer and manager.

A consumer can request a resource or release a resource

The manager can revoke a resource

When the manager receives a normal request it will deny it if it has no free resources. If it received a priority request it will force a revoke on some consumer (decided by some apropriate policy). This is similar to how a distributed lock system might work. This prevents starvation, but dramatically increases complexity and may not even be possible if a consumer simply must run to completion upon starting.

Failing this, I think Daren's answer is probably the most ideal, however, you still risk waste if you have no active consumers in a group and many active consumers in another group. That could be mitigated by good partitioning of the groups, though.