# Using .Net 4.0 new features for parallel tasks

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I've previously asked a [question about designing a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662232/design-queue-management-question-c) that receives video files, sends them to an encoding service, waits for the encoding to be completed, and then downloads the files.

I started writing the code for that and one of my workmates suggested I use .Net 4.0 new features, instead of writing it using BackgroundWorker. I've done some reading and the Parallel feature sounds great. Are there any more new features I should implement? I'm new to .net 4.0.

Thanks!

Comment: "use" or "adopt", not "implement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel Extensions is certainly one good option here. Another you might want to consider is [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx), which implements a "push" model instead. It takes a little while to get your head round, but it's very elegant - and might work very well with your asynchronous model.